# Mapping one type to another

Tags: go, automapper, go-gin

Let's say I have the following types.

```
type Contract struct {
    Id              string  `json:"id" gorm:"column:uuid"`
    Name            string  `json:"name" gorm:"column:name"`
    Description     string  `json:"descr" gorm:"column:descr"`
    ContractTypeId  int     `json:"contract_type_id" gorm:"column:contract_type_id"`
}

type ContractModel struct {
    Id              string  `json:"id" gorm:"column:uuid"`
    Name            string  `json:"name" gorm:"column:name"`
    Description     string  `json:"descr" gorm:"column:descr"`
}
```

I have a SQL query using `gorm` to scan results into a contract object.

How can I map the values from the contract object into contractModel object?

I tried using the package [`go-automapper`](https://godoc.org/github.com/PeteProgrammer/go-automapper) as such:

```
automapper.Map(contract, ContractModel{})
```

I want to drop the `ContractTypeId`.

Can I do this for multiple types in a list?

```
var contractModels []ContractModel
automapper.Map(contracts, &contractModels)
```

Comment: *"I want to drop the `ContractTypeId`."* -- You could do `contract.ContractTypeId = 0` if by "drop" you mean unset. If by "drop" you mean "remove" the field completely then that's not possible, types in Go are static, hence you cannot add nor remove fields from `Contract` at runtime.

Comment: If what you want is to copy the field values from `contract` to an instance of type `ContractModel` which would automatically omit `ContractTypeId` since that field is not present in `ContractModel` then you have to first allocate an instance and then pass a pointer to it to `autmapper.Map` as the `dest` argument. e.g. `var cm ContractModel`; `automapper.Map(contract, &cm)`; `fmt.Println(cm)`.

Comment: @mkopriva, this totally makes sense and worked for me. Thanks so much. Another question, what if I have a list of `contracts`, can I do something like the edit?

Comment: You have to iterate the slice and copy each item individually to the new type and add it to a new list. You can pre-allocate the size of the new slice to make this fast: `newSlice := make([]ContractModel, 0, len(oldSlice))`. Then use `append` to append the items.

Comment: @sgerbhctim AFAICT from looking at the [source](https://github.com/stroiman/go-automapper/blob/master/automapper.go#L81), yes, you should be able to do something like in the edit. Have you tried it?

Answer (score 1):

You can do either:

```golang
models := []ContractModel{}
automapper.Map(contracts, &models)
```

Or call `automapper.Map` in a loop:

```golang
models := make([]ContractModel, len(contracts))
for i := range contracts {
    automapper.Map(contracts[i], &models[i])
}
```

You should be aware that automapper uses reflection behind the scenes and thus is much slower than straight forward non-polymorphic copying like @ThinkGoodly suggests. It's a totally fine solution if performance isn't top priority though.

Comment: The link you shared is for Automapper for .NET, this one is for Golang. I guess if it saves you a bunch of tedious coding it’s worth it, and if one suspect it really affects performance the best path forward is to break out the profiler anyway.