# Copy field values from one type to instance of another type in list

Tags: go, types, model, automapper, go-gin

Assume I have 2 structs as such:

```
type Contract struct {
    Id              string  `json:"id" gorm:"column:uuid"`
    Name            string  `json:"name" gorm:"column:name"`
    Description     string  `json:"descr" gorm:"column:descr"`
    ContractTypeId  int     `json:"contract_type_id" gorm:"column:contract_type_id"`
}

type ContractModel struct {
    Id              string  `json:"id" gorm:"column:uuid"`
    Name            string  `json:"name" gorm:"column:name"`
    Description     string  `json:"descr" gorm:"column:descr"`
}
```

As I run a SQL query and scan the results into the `Contract` type, I have successfully mapped the values over to `ContractModel` as such using the `go-automapper` package.

```
var contractModel ContractModel
automapper.Map(contract, &contractModel)
```

Now, lets assume I am returned an array of `contracts`.

What can I do to automap all the values in the array, i.e.,

```
var contractModels []ContractModel
automapper.Map(contracts, &contractModels)
```

I know this does not make sense. I am new to Golang and not sure which mapping syntax to use.

---

EDIT:

Does this seem correct?

```
            var contractModels []domain.ContractModel
            for i := 0; i < len(contracts); i++ {
                var contractModel domain.ContractModel
                automapper.Map(contracts, &contractModel)
                contractModels = append(contractModels, contractModel)
            }
```

Issue I am hitting is `Invalid argument for len`.

Comment: [You just asked an almost identical question earlier today](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65584357/mapping-one-type-to-another-in-go), please don't post duplicates. You can edit your previous question if you need to.

Comment: @ThinkGoodly there are no cleaner, one-liners that can handle that?

Comment: Edit above @ThinkGoodly

Answer (score 1):

Create a slice of the destination values.  Loop over the source values and assign fields to the destination values as needed.

```
contractModels := make([]ContractModel, len(contracts))
for i, v := range contracts {
    contractModels[i] = ContractModel{Id: v.Id, Name: v.Name, Description: v.Description}
}
```